# EXCEL Filter Columns - Containing Numbers Greater Than X

Tags: excel, google-analytics, excel-formula

So here's an example of my data in one of the columns

```
/festivals/upcoming
/win/competitions/572
/latest/reviews/14940 --- THIS ONE TO BE SHOWN
/latest/news/15521
/download-festival-2014/lineup
```

Is it possible to filter this column so the 3rd one down (as commented) to be shown. What I need to do is take the last string after the last forward slash, check if it's a number, if it is a number and if it's less than 14650, to keep it

I exported the excel from google analytics so if it's easier to do there, then all good!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if the data was in A1 to An do this, and drag down:  =IF(IFERROR(VALUE(TRIM(CLEAN(TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"/",REPT(" ",99)),(2-COLUMN(A1))*99),99))))),"")>14650,IFERROR(VALUE(TRIM(CLEAN(TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"/",REPT(" ",99)),(2-COLUMN(A1))*99),99))))),""),"")